# How can I put a date in Spanish in angular? I have the following code

Tags: angular

How can I put a date in Spanish in Angular? I have the following code:

```
<a>{{currentDate | date:"medium"}}</a><b>|</b><a>{{name}}</a>
```

Comment: date.toLocaleDateString();

Comment: Sorry, this by far too less information. Please tell us what your date is expected to look like.

Comment: april- abril, example. october-octubre in spanish

Comment: Check my answer I fixed the same issue with that.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the [documentation of pipeline](https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe) or [Documentation of Locale](https://angular.io/api/core/LOCALE_ID) help you.

In your app.module

```
import { LOCALE_ID } from '@angular/core';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule, {
  providers: [{provide: LOCALE_ID, useValue: 'es-ES' }]
});
```

in you HTML you just put the format

```
{{currentDate | date: 'dd/mm/yyyy'}}
```

OR you can use [angular-i18n](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-i18n) or [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/)

Answer (score 1):

You should install **angular-i18n** via bower or npm. For spanish add this in your index.

bower

```
<script src="/bower_components/angular-i18n/angular-locale_es-es.js"></script>
```

node

```
<script src="/node_modules/angular-i18n/angular-locale_es-es.js"></script>
```

Repo site: https://github.com/angular/bower-angular-i18n